# How to parse tables from .txt files using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract tables from log files which are in .txt format. The file is loaded using `read_csv()` from `pandas`.

The log file looks like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc

=====================
A   B   C   D   E   F
=====================
1   2   3   4   5   6
7   8   9   1   2   3
4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6
---------------------

=====================
G     H     I     J
=====================
1           3     4
5           6     7
---------------------

=====================
K    L    M    N    O
=====================
1              2    3
4    5              6
7    8         9
---------------------

xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Here are some points about the log file:

- Files start and end with some lines of comment which can be ignored.
- In the example above there are three tables.
- Headers for each table are located between lines of "======..."
- The end of each table is signified by a line of "------..."

My code as of now:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv("xxx.txt", sep="\n", header=None)

# delimiters for header and end-of-table

h_dl = "=" * 21
r_dl = "-" * 21

for i in range(len(df.index)-2):

    # if loop to find lines which are table headers & convert to list    

    if (df.iloc[i].any() == h_dl) & (df.iloc[i+2].any() == h_dl):

        h = df.iloc[i+1].str.split().tolist()
        h = list(itertools.chain(*h))


        # while loop to find lines which are table rows & append to one list

        x = 3
        r = []

        while True:

            if df.iloc[i+x].any() == r_dl:
                break

            r.append(df.iloc[i+x].str.split().tolist())
            x += 1

        r = list(itertools.chain(*r))

        # create pandas dataframe with header and rows obtained above
        t = pd.DataFrame(data=r, columns=h)
```

This code returns `AssertionError: 14 columns passed, passed data had 15 columns`. I know that this is due to the fact that for the table rows, I am using `.str.split()` which by default splits on whitespace. Since there are some columns for which there are missing values, the number of elements in table headers and number of elements in table rows does not match for the second and htird table. I am struggling to get around this, since the number of whitespace characters to signify missing values is different for each table.

My question is: is there a way to account for missing values in some of the columns, so that I can get a DataFrame as output where there are either null or NaN for missing values as appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With usage of Victor Ruiz method I added if options to handle different header sizes.

=^..^=

Description in code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv("stack.txt", sep="\n", header=None)

# delimiters for header and end-of-table

h_dl = "=" * 21
r_dl = "-" * 21

for i in range(len(df.index)-2):

    # if loop to find lines which are table headers & convert to list
    if (df.iloc[i].any() == h_dl) & (df.iloc[i+2].any() == h_dl):

        h = df.iloc[i+1].str.split().tolist()
        h = list(itertools.chain(*h))

        # get header string
        head = df.iloc[i+1].to_string()
        # get space distance in header
        space_range = 0
        for result in re.findall('([ ]*)', head):
            if len(result) > 0:
                space_range = len(result)

        x = 3
        r = []
        while True:
            if df.iloc[i+x].any() == r_dl:
                break

            # strip line
            line = df.iloc[i+x].to_string()[5::]

            # collect items based on elements distance
            items = []
            for result in re.finditer('(\d+)([ ]*)', line):
                item, delimiter = result.groups()
                items.append(item)
                if len(delimiter) > space_range*2+1:
                    items.append('NaN')
                    items.append('NaN')
                if len(delimiter) < space_range*2+2 and len(delimiter) > space_range:
                    items.append('NaN')
            r.append([items])

            x += 1

        r = list(itertools.chain(*r))

        # create pandas dataframe with header and rows obtained above
        t = pd.DataFrame(data=r, columns=h)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  7  8  9  1  2  3
2  4  5  6  7  8  9
3  1  2  3  4  5  6

   G    H  I  J
0  1  NaN  3  4
1  5  NaN  6  7

   K    L    M    N     O
0  1  NaN  NaN    2     3
1  4    5  NaN  NaN     6
2  7    8  NaN    9  None
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the output I was looking for! Just one thing I would like to clarify...when you "strip line" with `line = df.iloc[i+x].to_string()[5::]`, what is the purpose of the indexing at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.
Suppose we have the next line of text:

```
1           3     4
```

The problem is to identify how much spaces delimits two consecutive items without considering that there is a missing value between them. 
Let consider that 5 spaces is a delimiter, and more than 5 is a missing value.

You can use regex to parse the items:

```py
from re import finditer

line = '1           3     4'
items = []

for result in finditer('(\d+)([ ]*)', line):
    item, delimiter = result.groups()
    items.append(item)
    if len(delimiter) > 5:
        items.append(nan)
print(items)
```

Output is:

```
['1', nan, '3', '4']
```

A more complex situation would be if it can appear two or more consecutive missing values (the code above will just inyect only one nan)

Comment: Thanks, this use of regex provides an insight into how I should design my parser. I regret that I do not have the privilege to up vote answers...